# Checking if any property has been assigned a value

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a type `SearchBag` that holds a bunch of strings and nullable integers to use for passing on search values. I need a way to check if the search bag contains any values.

I'm currently trying to do it like this:

```
    public bool HasValues()
    {
        return GetType().GetProperties().Any(p => p.GetValue(this, null) != null);
    }
```

But was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: In my mind, this is a completely valid way to do it unless you have major performance concerns.

Comment: Not sure it's a better way but you could implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without modifying the `SearchBag` type, there isn't a better way.

**EDIT**: You could change the type to set a boolean flag in every property setter, then check the flag instead of using Reflection.

Comment: Thx. Yes thought about that but that would require me to convert all auto properties to value backed properties and implement the logic in each setter. It's an option, but I think the reflection cost is not worth it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Post Sharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) to intercept the request to change a property value. You could have all search classes inherit from a common class with a `List<string>`. Then create an aspect attribute to add a property name to that dictionary whenever the value changes. The following is just a sample, and has bugs:

```
[Serializable]
public class PropertyChangeAwareAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs.Method.Name.StartsWith("set_")) 
            ((SearchBagBase)eventArgs.Instance).PropertiesChanged.Add(eventArgs.Method.Name);
        base.OnEntry(eventArgs);
    }
}


abstract class SearchBagBase
{
    public List<string> PropertiesChanged = new List<String>();
}

[PropertyChangeAware]
class RegularSearch : SearchBagBase
{
    public String Key { get; set; }
}
```

with usage:

```
RegularSearch regularSearch = new RegularSearch();
regularSearch.Key = "toys";
regularSearch.PropertiesChanged.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: As I'm unfamiliar with PostSharp I had a quick glance at Post Sharp. Looking forward to your example

Comment: Not sure the reflector overhead in my particular case is worth the trouble, but it seems like an interesting library on a whole. I will keep this in mind for later use. Thx :)

Comment: @boris I created a solution using this library to tell if a piece of data from the database was dirty or not. It ended up being reusable in many other situations.